# What is the runtime of $T(n)= \frac{27}{7} n^2− \frac{20}{7} 2^{\log_3(n)}$ using Big-$O$ notation?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

If I have the runtime of: $$T(n)=  \frac{27}{7} n^2− \frac{20}{7} 2^{\log_3(n)}$$
Is it correct that its Big-$O$ Notation is $2^n$?
Because what puzzles me is that while $n^2$ runs slower than $2^n$, by the log, indeed $2^{\log}...$ should run slower?

Comment: The edit by Piita did not typeset the original expression correctly.

Comment: Yeah, we got that for exercise but it irritated me a lot. Because of that it would be really nice if someone can help me

Comment: Answer: No it is not correct, exactly for the reason you mention. Instead, use that $2^{\log_3(n)}=2^{c\log_2(n)}=n^c,$ for $c=\log_3(2),$ and note that $\log_3(2)<2.$

Comment: Okay, so I can say that the runtime is n^2?

Comment: In general, you will probably have to learn, eventually, how to deal with expressions of the form $a^{\log_b n}$; for this, you will want to know formulas such as $\log_a n = \frac{\log_b n}{\log_b a}$. It's better if you also learn how to derive these formulas—that will often help you to remember them, because it is easy to get them the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Remember that $e^{\log(n)}=n$, see if you can use this to your advantage

Comment: Yeah, that i was thinking but because of the third base of log I think it is not possible

Comment: $\log_a(b)=\frac{\log(b)}{\log(a)}$ which you can use to switch the bases around

Comment: But that doesn’t help me, or maybe I’m to stupid

Comment: Try applying other log rules to the term, in particular remember that $a^{mn} = (a^m)^n = (a^n)^m$.